# What is the threat/risk difference in opening multiple ports on one physical NIC on a home server vs creating VLANs and opening ports on each VLAN?

Tags: network, server, ports, port-forwarding, vlans

I have a single home server with a single NIC. I intend to run numerous services -- some will be internet exposed, some will not. I don't know if I am going to run them as VMs or Docker container but it shouldn't matter for this question.

Say I ultimately need to open port:

- `:1234` that'll accept traffic from the internet (using a port forward on my router)
- `:6789` that'll accept traffic just from my local network

I figure I have two options:

1. open both ports `:1234` and `:6789` on `eth0` of my server
2. use VLANs:

   1. create a 802.1Q trunk on `eth0` of my server then
   2. create two VLANs:

      - `eth0.10` - dmz
      - `eth0.20` - trust
   3. open ports on the individual VLANs:

      - `:1234` on `eth0.10`
      - `:6789` on `eth0.20`

The way I see it, option 2 gives me more control on my router/FW for rules for traffic between two VLANs but I am wondering how much it matters if everything is ultimately going to the same ethernet port on the same server.

So I'm wondering from a risk/threat perspective, is one better than the other?

Comment: The second one does mean an attacker can't connect to port 6789 from the internet

Comment: But I am opening 6789 on the server, not router, so it wouldn't be accessible from the internet. No?

Comment: the home router DMZ setting that I'm aware of automatically forwards *all* ports. Does your one not work that way?

Comment: I’m not forwarding all ports. Just the ports I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any security related reason to use VLANs in this case. As you said, you are exposing the same server either way after all.

Now, if you had multiple internal networks with different levels of trust, VLANs may be useful.

Comment: Thanks. I figure using VLANs gives me centralized logging cause everything is going through pfSense but that is about it. If you don't mind, I'll leave the answer unmarked for a few days to see if anyone else chimes in.